# Unable to pass data between two components in Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'm very new to Angular and I'm having difficulty passing data from a parent to child component. I have a product listing page where you click on a product and it routes to the product detail page. But I can't seem to get the product details to show.

Component 1: Contains all the product data.
Component 2: Routes to a new page where said product data is displayed.

product list (parent) component file:

```js
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { IProduct } from "./product";
import { ProductService } from "./product.service";

@Component({
    templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})

export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    pageTitle = 'Anthony\'s Product List';
    imageWidth = 50;
    imageMargin = 2;
    showImage: boolean = true;
    errorMessage: string = '';
    sub!: Subscription;
    
    private _listFilter: string = '';
    get listFilter(): string {
       return this._listFilter 
    }
    set listFilter(value: string) {
        this._listFilter = value;
        console.log('In setter:', value);
        this.filteredProducts = this.performFilter(value);
    }

    filteredProducts: IProduct[] = [];
    products: IProduct[] = [];

    //defining the injector so it can be used in this class
        constructor(private productService: ProductService) {}

    //this is a method

    performFilter(filterBy: string): IProduct[] {
        filterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
        return this.products.filter((product: IProduct) =>
            product.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(filterBy));
    }
    
    toggleImage(): void {
        this.showImage = !this.showImage;
    }
    //this lifecycle hook retrives the data we need
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.productService.getProducts().subscribe({
            next: products => {
                this.products = products;
                this.filteredProducts = this.products;
            },
            error: err => this.errorMessage = err
        });
        
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        //this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }

    onRatingClicked(message: string): void {
        this.pageTitle = 'Product List: ' + message;
    }
    
}
```

Parent component HTML:

```html
<div class='card'>
    <div class='card-header'>
        {{pageTitle}}
    </div>
    <div class='card-body'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-2'>Filter by:</div>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <input type='text' 
                    [(ngModel)]='listFilter' />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-6'>
                <h4>Filtered by: {{listFilter}} </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='table-responsive'>
            <table class='table' *ngIf='products.length'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <button class='btn btn-primary'
                                (click)='toggleImage()'>
                                    {{showImage ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}} Image
                            </button>
                        </th>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Code</th>
                        <th>Available</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>5 Star Rating</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor='let product of filteredProducts'>
                        <td>
                            <img *ngIf='showImage'
                            [src]='product.imageUrl'
                            [title]='product.productName'
                            [style.width.px]='imageWidth'
                            [style.margin.px]='imageMargin'>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a [routerLink]="['/products', product.productId]">
                            {{product.productName}}
                            </a>
                        </td>   
                        <td>{{product.productCode | convertToSpaces:'-' }}</td>
                        <td>{{product.releaseDate}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.price | currency:'AUD'}}</td>
                        <td><pm-star [rating]='product.starRating'
                            (ratingClicked)='onRatingClicked($event)'>
                        </pm-star></td> 
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Product detail component file:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { IProduct } from '../product/product';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './product-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-detail.component.css']
})
export class ProductDetailComponent implements OnInit  {
  product: IProduct | undefined;
  pageTitle: any = 'Product Detail';

  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, 
              private router: Router) { }
  
              ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.pageTitle += `: ${id}`;
  }
    
    onBack(): void {
      this.router.navigate(['/products']);
    }

  }
```

Child component HTML file:

```html
<div class='card'>
    <div class='card-header'>
        {{pageTitle + ': ' + product?.productName}}
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class='card-body'>
        <div class='col-md-4'>Code:</div>
        <div class='col-md-8'>{{product?.productCode}}</div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div class='card-footer'>
        <button class='btn btn-outline-secondary'
                style='width:80px'
                (click)='onBack()'>
            <i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i> Back
            </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Json file with a snippet of product data:

```js
[
    {
      "productId": 1,
      "productName": "Leaf Rake",
      "productCode": "GDN-0011",
      "releaseDate": "March 19, 2019",
      "description": "Leaf rake with 48-inch wooden handle.",
      "price": 19.95,
      "starRating": 3.2,
      "imageUrl": "assets/images/leaf_rake.png"
    },
    {
      "productId": 2,
      "productName": "Garden Cart",
      "productCode": "GDN-0023",
      "releaseDate": "March 18, 2019",
      "description": "15 gallon capacity rolling garden cart",
      "price": 32.99,
      "starRating": 4.2,
      "imageUrl": "assets/images/garden_cart.png"
    },
```

Produce service TS file:

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { catchError, Observable, tap, throwError } from "rxjs";

import { IProduct } from "./product";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {
  private productUrl = 'api/products/products.json';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productUrl).pipe(
    tap(data => console.log('All: ', JSON.stringify(data))),
    catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

I've just started learning, so please ignore any mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

add a property in `ProductService` and assign the currently clicked row data, then in the child component access the data using the same service then render the output.

in the parent component. Suppose we have a event that navigates to child. You need to set the latest value in the service like so.

parent component

```
openProduct(product): void {
    this.productService.product = product;
    this.router.navigate(['/products', product.productId]);
}
```

parent component html

```
<div class='card'>
    <div class='card-header'>
        {{pageTitle}}
    </div>
    <div class='card-body'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-2'>Filter by:</div>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <input type='text' 
                    [(ngModel)]='listFilter' />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-6'>
                <h4>Filtered by: {{listFilter}} </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='table-responsive'>
            <table class='table' *ngIf='products.length'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <button class='btn btn-primary'
                                (click)='toggleImage()'>
                                    {{showImage ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}} Image
                            </button>
                        </th>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Code</th>
                        <th>Available</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>5 Star Rating</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor='let product of filteredProducts'>
                        <td>
                            <img *ngIf='showImage'
                            [src]='product.imageUrl'
                            [title]='product.productName'
                            [style.width.px]='imageWidth'
                            [style.margin.px]='imageMargin'>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a (click)="openProduct(product)">
                            {{product.productName}}
                            </a>
                        </td>   
                        <td>{{product.productCode | convertToSpaces:'-' }}</td>
                        <td>{{product.releaseDate}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.price | currency:'AUD'}}</td>
                        <td><pm-star [rating]='product.starRating'
                            (ratingClicked)='onRatingClicked($event)'>
                        </pm-star></td> 
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

child component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { IProduct } from '../product/product';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './product-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-detail.component.css']
})
export class ProductDetailComponent implements OnInit  {
  product: IProduct | undefined;
  pageTitle: any = 'Product Detail';

  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, 
              private router: Router, 
              private productService: ProductService) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.pageTitle += `: ${id}`;
    // get the data from the service.
    this.product = this.productService.product;
  }
    
  onBack(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/products']);
  }
}
```

product service.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { catchError, Observable, tap, throwError } from "rxjs";

import { IProduct } from "./product";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {
  private productUrl = 'api/products/products.json';
  product: IProduct | undefined;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productUrl).pipe(
    tap(data => console.log('All: ', JSON.stringify(data))),
    catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

Note: this solution wont work when you refresh the detail page, so ideally you need to create a separate api call, that will fetch the details of a single product based on the ID and call it on the `ngOnInit` of the child component!

Comment: thanks for this. I've added in the parent component TS file, as I'm unsure the exact spot where to place that first snippet of code you provided.

Comment: @AntMar Please share the parent component html also to solve your issue!

Comment: Just added that in, thanks @Naren-Murali

Comment: in the product service file, I'm getting an error with product: IProduct; (TS2564)

Comment: @AntMar sorry I'm only able to help you this much with the data provided updated my answer, if ur still facing issues replicate the issue on a stackblitz and share back